# Limit number of x tics for time

Tags: gnuplot

I have data formatted with a typical time value for x.  The data come from a file which is appended every 15 minutes.

```
2014-05-28 12:34:56.7890,123,456,789
```

Plots perfectly well, but the xtics all run together. What I would like to do is plot the last 72 hours (the most recent 288 observations) and have tics for today - 2 days, today - 1 day, and today placed at 00:00:00.

```
.....|...............|...............|.....
    Mon             Tue             Wed
```

But this is where I run into trouble.

I suppose that I could add the day name into the data file and plot that, but this seems like something that should be doable in gnuplot. I've been chasing my tail on this one.

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do some calculations for the position of your xtics with `strptime` and `strftime`:

```
now = time(0)
today_midnight = strptime('%Y-%m-%d', strftime('%Y-%m-%d', now))
set xrange [now - 72*60*60 : now]
set xtics now-72*60*60, 24*60*60
set format x '%a'
```

This sets the `xrange` to the last 72 hours and places a tic for every midnight, which is labeled with the abbreviated name of the day of the week (`%a` format).

Comment: Wow. This is an elegant, easy to understand solution. Is "gnuplotic" a word? It should be. Thanks very much.